# How to delete more than one node with xml-query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xquery

with this code, I can remove one node (field_without_interest) of this xml element.
But I would like to remove two nodes now( field_without_interest and  PERSON_NUMBER).
I have tried to place the for loop at differents places (You can see that in code. But I don't think it useful to for to write every attemps in stackoverflow) but to no avail.

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         'copy $NEWHTML := .
         modify (
           for $i in $NEWHTML/ROWSET/ROW/field_without_interest
           --for $j in $NEWHTML/ROWSET/ROW/PERSON_NUMBER
           return delete node $i--, node $j
         )
         return $NEWHTML'
         PASSING xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <field_without_interest>f</field_without_interest>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
)
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getStringVal() AS interested_elements
FROM   DUAL
```

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ba12b5f5620f0d52f56575af84c2cdb6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify path alternatives in the `modify` clause to select nodes to delete:

> ```
> SELECT XMLQUERY(
>   'copy $NEWHTML := .
>   modify (
>     delete nodes
>     $NEWHTML/ROWSET/ROW/*[
>       self::field_without_interest
>       or self::PERSON_NUMBER
>     ]
>   )
>   return $NEWHTML'
>   PASSING xmltype(
>   '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
>   <ROWSET> 
>     <ROW>
>       <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
>       <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
>       <field_without_interest>f</field_without_interest>
>     </ROW> 
>     <ROW>
>       <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
>       <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
>     </ROW> 
>   </ROWSET>'
> )
>   RETURNING CONTENT
>   ).getStringVal() AS interested_elements
> FROM   DUAL
> ```
>
> ```
> | INTERESTED_ELEMENTS                                                                                      |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <?xml version="1.0"?><ROWSET><ROW><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1></ROW><ROW><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1></ROW></ROWSET> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dfa867e8308a55cf534796cfec29d2b2)*